# Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas dataframe (python), it is currently in this format:

df = [image]

I am trying to convert the above dataframe into a new dataframe in below format:

new_df = [image]

I am trying to avoid doing this using a lot of code as performance will be impacted, is there some dataframe function that can be used to achieve this?

Comment: If first column is index solution is `df1 = df.unstack().reset_index(name='count')`

Comment: I tried this but I get: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.. Count in above example is integer but I am using float in dataframe..

Comment: So solutions from dupe not working?

Comment: pd.melt did work - the issue was with data type used within dataframe so you can leave this question as marked as duplicate.